# How can I display only the first 10 inputs from the list?

Tags: c, list, struct, singly-linked-list, function-definition

I'm inserting in a list of struct some details that each fourplet represents a packet with source, destination, generation time and a rollnumber?
Here is my display function and in the main() I just call her: display(); in the end of the main code. How can I display only the first 10 packets (fourplets) from the list, that I inserted before with the insert function below?

```
struct Packet{
 int rollnumber;
 int src;
 int dest;
 double gentime;
 struct Packet *next;
 }* head;    

void display(){
 struct Packet * temp = head;
 while(temp!=NULL){
    printf("Roll Number: %d\n",temp->rollnumber);
    printf("src: %d\n", temp->src);
    printf("dest: %d\n", temp->dest);
    printf("gentime: %0.1f\n\n", temp->gentime);
    temp = temp->next;
    }
 }

 void insert(int rollnumber, int src, int dest, double gentime){
  struct Packet * packet = (struct Packet *) malloc(sizeof(struct Packet));
  packet->rollnumber = rollnumber;
  packet->src=src;
  packet->dest=dest;
  packet->gentime = gentime;
  packet->next = NULL;

  if(head==NULL){
    head = packet;
  }
  else{
    packet->next = head;
    head = packet;
   }
  }
```

Comment: And what is the problem? Display only 10 packets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write the function `display` for example the following way

```
void display( size_t n )
{
    if ( n == 0 ) n = ( size_t )-1;

    for ( struct Packet * temp = head; n-- && temp != NULL; temp = temp->next )
    {  
        printf("Roll Number: %d\n",temp->rollnumber);
        printf("src: %d\n", temp->src);
        printf("dest: %d\n", temp->dest);
        printf("gentime: %0.1f\n\n", temp->gentime);
    }
}
```

And call the function for example like

```
display( 10 );
```

When the function is called with the argument equal to `0` then the function outputs the whole list.

Comment: Can I do the same with the insert function?

Comment: @wajaap You may do anything you want.:)

Comment: I tried it and it displays nothing, which make me think that it does not work the same with the insert function.

Comment: @wajaap You can ask a new question with your new problem closing this question and selecting the best answer.